# kivy logging; 'Too many logfile, remove them'

Tags: python, logging, kivy

When using kivy logging like this:

```
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.config import Config


Config.set('kivy', 'log_enable', 1)
Config.set('kivy', 'log_dir', '/home/dude/folder')
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'debug')
Config.set('kivy', 'log_name', 'my_file.log')
Config.write()

Logger.debug('main:switching stuff on')
Logger.info('socket:send command to raspberry')
```

I always get the the error:

```
[ERROR  ] Error while activating FileHandler logger
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 220, in emit
    self._configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 171, in _configure
    raise Exception('Too many logfile, remove them')
Exception: Too many logfile, remove them
```

... even after removing any file with this name.
What am I missing here?

I also get the error when running bigger programs which actually contain kivy widgets and apps.

Comment: Try looking into `.kivy/logs` folder too, but those should be purged automatically.

Comment: Indeed, that directory was full of log files. But still, aber deleting all of these too, i still get the same behavior. 
Indeed, i get this behavior on the a Linux Ubuntu laptop (kivy runs on python 2.7) and a raspberry (kivy runs on python3).

Comment: Have you checked that this error is not caused by wrong permissions?

Comment: I don't thing that this is the problem, running with or without sudo, the same occurs.
In the [source code from kivy logger](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/logger.html) the exception seems to be raised in connection with some variable n:
´if n > 10000:  # prevent maybe flooding ?´
       ´raise Exception('Too many logfile, remove them')´

Comment: As you can see, in the answer, i got it working. But is there a way to append, if there exists already a file with such a name?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the correct settings in the /home/.kivy/config.ini file solved the problem. All existing files in the set directory have to be removed. Kivy logger does not append in an existing file. It just raises the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because kivy Logger does not actually have a single file when dumping stdout into a text file (possibly due to it calling the handler multiple times not sure). Rather it will occasionally raise another file with a number appendage (replacing %_) and continue logging. However, if for whatever reason it cannot append this number or the count reaches over 10k, then it will raise the above exception and exit the app. Great if you want to avoid flooding, as the notes in the kivy code indicate, not so great when you were not aware of kivy naming convention.

Kivy Logger -> https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/logger.html